How can we use Python to extract Arabic words from a string of text?
Suppose that we have a string of text that contains a mixture of English words and Arabic words.
Our goal is to extract the Arabic words and omit or delete all English words.
Input:
The initial Baa’ “ب” :
Arabic  English Pronunciation
بحيرة   Lake    Buhayra
بصل Onion   Bassal
بطة Duck    Batta

Output:
ب
بحيرة
بصل
بطة


What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Interesting that the editing of the question removed characters that make the answer to the question simpler, and right for the  edited example, but not quite accurate for the original data. Its good to simplify the example and produce a minimal reproducible example, but it should reflect the diversity in the original data before simplification. There are no examples of fatḥah, kasrah, ḍammah, sukūn, taṭwīl or ZWJ in the edited input, which can potential change the nature of the answer.

|'d tend towards a simpler solution, targeting Arabic script words using the regex module, and using either POSIX r'\b[[:Arabic:]]+\b' or Perl '\b\p{Arabic}+\b' notation, I.e. look for a text sequence of one Arabic character or longer delineated by word boundaries:
# First install regex module:
#    pip install -U regex

import regex

# Read in text into variable data

# arabic_tokens = regex.findall(r'\b[[:Arabic:]]+\b', data)
arabic_tokens = regex.findall(r'\b\p{Arabic}+\b', data)
print(arabic_tokens)
# ['ب', 'ب', 'ب', 'ب', 'ب', 'ب', 'ب', 'بحيرة', 'بصل', 'بطة', 'ب', 'طبيب', 'خبز', 'صباح', 'ربيع', 'صابون', 'إبرة', 'ب', 'زبيب', 'عنب', 'أرنب', 'كتاب', 'حجاب', 'باب', 'ب', 'الحركات', 'فتحة', 'ضمة', 'كسرة', 'سكون', 'ب', 'بطريق']

You can then sort the results. My macOS doesn't have Arabic locale support , so I'll use PyICU instead of locale:
import icu
collator = icu.Collator.createInstance(icu.Locale('ar'))
arabic_tokens_sorted = sorted(arabic_tokens, key=collator.getSortKey)
print(arabic_tokens_sorted)
# ['إبرة', 'أرنب', 'الحركات', 'ب', 'ب', 'ب', 'ب', 'ب', 'ب', 'ب', 'ب', 'ب', 'ب', 'ب', 'باب', 'بحيرة', 'بصل', 'بطة', 'بطريق', 'حجاب', 'خبز', 'ربيع', 'زبيب', 'سكون', 'صابون', 'صباح', 'ضمة', 'طبيب', 'عنب', 'فتحة', 'كتاب', 'كسرة']

Correction 8 Jun 24:
My initial answer is not correct and needs to be modified in a few ways. The answer has been edited and made clearer, but has changed the nature of the data. If I go back to the original data, the data included Arabic script words containing three ḥarakāt (fatḥah, kasrah, and ḍammah) or short vowel marks, sukūn and taṭwīl. These characters are not classified as part of the Arabic script. Fatḥah, kasrah, ḍammah, and sukūn are non-spacing marks used in more than one script and are part of a script Unicode refers to as Inherited.
Taṭwīl is an older typesetting convention that is usually replaced by more sophisticated OpenType rendering, but can sometimes be found in plaintext. Examples in the data are: {'ــبـــ', 'ــب', 'بـــــ'}.
Obviously the words that the question wants to cover include the non-spacing marks, so better code would include the Inherited script:
arabic_tokens = regex.findall(r'\b[\p{Arabic}\p{Inherited}]+\b', data)
arabic_tokens
['ب', 'ب', 'ب', 'ب', 'ب', 'ب', 'ب', 'بحيرة', 'بصل', 'بطة', 'ب', 'طبيب', 'خبز', 'صباح', 'ربيع', 'صابون', 'إبرة', 'ب', 'زبيب', 'عنب', 'أرنب', 'كتاب', 'حجاب', 'باب', 'ب', 'الحركات', 'فتحة', 'بَذرة', 'بَسمة', 'بَدر', 'بُ', 'ضمة', 'بُحيرة', 'بُستان', 'بُندقية', 'بِ', 'كسرة', 'بِرميل', 'بِساط', 'بِنطال', 'بْ', 'سكون', 'أبْ', 'دبْ', 'شبْل', '\u200d', 'ب', 'بطريق']

This captures the odd use of U+200D (ZERO WIDTH JOINER), but it is not used word internal so can be removed. N.B. if you were tokenising other Arabic script languages, it would be critical to keep ZWJ and ZWNJ in text. If there is only one occurrence, as in this case, I'd use list.remove(), but in this example assuming an unknown number of occurrences, I'll fall back to a list comprehension:
arabic_tokens = [word for word in arabic_tokens if word != '\u200d']
>>> arabic_tokens
['ب', 'ب', 'ب', 'ب', 'ب', 'ب', 'ب', 'بحيرة', 'بصل', 'بطة', 'ب', 'طبيب', 'خبز', 'صباح', 'ربيع', 'صابون', 'إبرة', 'ب', 'زبيب', 'عنب', 'أرنب', 'كتاب', 'حجاب', 'باب', 'ب', 'الحركات', 'فتحة', 'بَذرة', 'بَسمة', 'بَدر', 'بُ', 'ضمة', 'بُحيرة', 'بُستان', 'بُندقية', 'بِ', 'كسرة', 'بِرميل', 'بِساط', 'بِنطال', 'بْ', 'سكون', 'أبْ', 'دبْ', 'شبْل', 'ب', 'بطريق']

Then this leaves the question of the taṭwīl, do the individual letters with taṭwīl need to be collected?, if so then you could target the Unicode block or update the character class being used in the regex pattern:
arabic_tokens = regex.findall(r'\b\p{Block=Arabic}+\b', data)
>>> arabic_tokens
['ب', 'ب', 'ب', 'ب', 'ــبـــ', 'بـــــ', 'ب', 'ب', 'ب', 'بحيرة', 'بصل', 'بطة', 'ب', 'طبيب', 'خبز', 'صباح', 'ربيع', 'صابون', 'إبرة', 'ب', 'زبيب', 'عنب', 'أرنب', 'كتاب', 'حجاب', 'باب', 'ب', 'الحركات', 'فتحة', 'بَذرة', 'بَسمة', 'بَدر', 'بُ', 'ضمة', 'بُحيرة', 'بُستان', 'بُندقية', 'بِ', 'كسرة', 'بِرميل', 'بِساط', 'بِنطال', 'بْ', 'سكون', 'أبْ', 'دبْ', 'شبْل', 'ــب', 'ب', 'بطريق']

This will include most tokens with taṭwīl and excludes the ZWJ. on of the words in source data is '\u200dــب'. This will be lost in this approach. So a compromise would be:
arabic_tokens = regex.findall(r'\b[\p{Arabic}\p{Inherited}\u0640]+\b', data)
arabic_tokens
# ['ب', 'ب', 'ب', 'ب', '\u200dــب', 'ــبـــ', 'بـــــ', 'ب', 'ب', 'ب', 'بحيرة', 'بصل', 'بطة', 'ب', 'طبيب', 'خبز', 'صباح', 'ربيع', 'صابون', 'إبرة', 'ب', 'زبيب', 'عنب', 'أرنب', 'كتاب', 'حجاب', 'باب', 'ب', 'الحركات', 'فتحة', 'بَذرة', 'بَسمة', 'بَدر', 'بُ', 'ضمة', 'بُحيرة', 'بُستان', 'بُندقية', 'بِ', 'كسرة', 'بِرميل', 'بِساط', 'بِنطال', 'بْ', 'سكون', 'أبْ', 'دبْ', 'شبْل', '\u200d', 'ــب', 'ب', 'بطريق']

# Clean results:
arabic_tokens = [word.strip('\u200d') for word in arabic_tokens if word != '\u200d']
arabic_tokens
# ['ب', 'ب', 'ب', 'ب', 'ــب', 'ــبـــ', 'بـــــ', 'ب', 'ب', 'ب', 'بحيرة', 'بصل', 'بطة', 'ب', 'طبيب', 'خبز', 'صباح', 'ربيع', 'صابون', 'إبرة', 'ب', 'زبيب', 'عنب', 'أرنب', 'كتاب', 'حجاب', 'باب', 'ب', 'الحركات', 'فتحة', 'بَذرة', 'بَسمة', 'بَدر', 'بُ', 'ضمة', 'بُحيرة', 'بُستان', 'بُندقية', 'بِ', 'كسرة', 'بِرميل', 'بِساط', 'بِنطال', 'بْ', 'سكون', 'أبْ', 'دبْ', 'شبْل', 'ــب', 'ب', 'بطريق']

If you wnat to capture the Arabic characters with taṭwīl, but not the taṭwīl, you could use:
arabic_tokens = regex.findall(r'\b[\p{Arabic}\p{Inherited}\u0640]+\b', data)
arabic_tokens = [regex.sub(r'[\u200d\u0640]' ,'' ,word) for word in arabic_tokens if word != '\u200d']
# ['ب', 'ب', 'ب', 'ب', 'ب', 'ب', 'ب', 'ب', 'ب', 'ب', 'بحيرة', 'بصل', 'بطة', 'ب', 'طبيب', 'خبز', 'صباح', 'ربيع', 'صابون', 'إبرة', 'ب', 'زبيب', 'عنب', 'أرنب', 'كتاب', 'حجاب', 'باب', 'ب', 'الحركات', 'فتحة', 'بَذرة', 'بَسمة', 'بَدر', 'بُ', 'ضمة', 'بُحيرة', 'بُستان', 'بُندقية', 'بِ', 'كسرة', 'بِرميل', 'بِساط', 'بِنطال', 'بْ', 'سكون', 'أبْ', 'دبْ', 'شبْل', 'ب', 'ب', 'بطريق'

Data used:
data = "'\nBaa’ is a simple and uncomplicated letter in the Arabic language, and it is an explosive oral sound. The shape of the letter Baa’ is one of the dotted letters, it resembles a plate with a dot under it, its complaint varies according to its location in the word, and the way it is pronounced varies according to its haraka.\n\nThe letter Baa’ has several types, and each type has its own function in the sentence.\n\nLet’s start explaining.\n\nContents  hide \n1. The shapes of the letter Baa’ “ب” :\n2. Examples of words with Baa’ “ب”:\n3. How to pronounce Baa’ “ب” :\nThe shapes of the letter Baa’ “ب” :\nTerminal    Middle  Initial Isolated\n\u200dــب    \n\nــبـــ\n\nبـــــ  ب\nExamples of words with Baa’ “ب”:\nWe will give you some examples to clarify and facilitate the lesson more.\n\n----------------------------------------------\nThe initial Baa’ “ب” :\nArabic  English Pronunciation\nبحيرة   Lake    Buhayra\nبصل Onion   Bassal\nبطة Duck    Batta\n\n----------------------------------------\nThe middle Baa’ “ب” \nArabic  English Pronunciation\nطبيب    Doctor  Ttabib\nخبز Bread   Khobz\nصباح    Morning Ssabah\n•Note:\nThe letter Baa’ in the middle of the word can be connected from the left side only.\n\n•Examples :\n\nArabic  English Pronunciation\nربيع    Spring  Rabie\nصابون   Soap    Ssaboon\nإبرة    Needle  ‘Ibra\nThe terminal Baa’ “ب”:\nArabic  English Pronunciation\nزبيب    Risins  Zabib\nعنب grapes  Einab\nأرنب    Rabbit  ‘Arnab\n\n•Note:\nThe letter Baa’ at the end of the word can be separate from the rest of the letters in the word.\n\n•Examples :\n\nArabic  English Pronunciation\nكتاب    Book    Kitab\nحجاب    Veil    Hijab\nباب Door    Bab\n\nHow to pronounce Baa’ “ب” :\nThe sound of the letter Baa’ is a loud, explosive, oral sound.The letter Baa’ in the phonetic alphabet is /b/.The letter Baa’ has 3 different types of sound:\n\nBaa’ with the harakat(الحركات):\nThe letter Baa’ with fathaبَ”فتحة” :\nThe letter “Baa’ ” in this case sounds like the letter “B” in the word “Baby”.\n\nArabic  English Pronunciation\nبَذرة   Seed    Badhra\nبَسمة   Smile   Basma\nبَدر    Full moon   Badr\nThe lettre Baa’ with damma بُ”ضمة”:\nThe letter “Baa’ ” in this case sounds like the letter “B” in the word “Bored”.\n\nArabic  English Pronunciation\nبُحيرة  Lake    Buhayra\nبُستان  Grove   Bustan\nبُندقية Gun Bunduqiya\nThe lettre Baa’ with kasra بِ”كسرة “:\nThe letter “Baa’ ” in this case sounds like the letter “B” in the word “Billion”.\n\nArabic  English Pronunciation\nبِرميل  Barrel  Birmil\nبِساط   Rug Bisatt\nبِنطال  Pants   Binttal\nThe lettre Baa’ with sukoon بْ”سكون”:\nThe letter “Baa’ ” in this case sounds like the letter “B” in the word “Brown”.\n\nArabic  English Pronunciation\nأبْ Father  ‘Ab\nدبْ Bear    Dob\nشبْل    Cub shibl\n\nThus, we have become well acquainted with the letter Baa’? I think that it has become a simple and intuitive lesson for you anymore. You have to repeat the information to benefit more from it. If you have any questions, please ask me and I will answer them personally. We will meet in the second episode of this educational series.\n\nBaa’ is the second lesson of the educational series: (Learn more about the Arabic alphabet with MSA Arabic), which provides detailed lessons for each letter of the Arabic alphabet from Alif to Yaa’ and it will be simplified and easy, follow with us.\n\nHow do we pronounce the letter Baa’ with a damma?\nwe say “Bo” like “Boss”\n\nWhat does the letter Baa’ look like at the end of the word?\n\u200d It is :ــب or ب\n\nHow do we pronounce the word “بطريق”?\nIt is:”Bitreeq”\n'"


The easy way to do it is using regular expressions. First, looking at where Arabic script is in Unicode, we see that regular expression for an Arabic character is
[\u0600-\u06FF\u0750-\u077F\u0870-\u089F\u08A0-\u08FF\uFB50-\uFDFF\uFE70-\uFEFF\U00010E60\U00010E7F\U00010EC0-\U00010EFF\U0001EC70-\U0001ECBF\U0001ED00-\U0001ED4F\U0001EE00-\U0001EEFF]

Extract all Arabic words from text as a list:
import re

arabic_word_list = re.findall(r"[\u0600-\u06FF\u0750-\u077F\u0870-\u089F\u08A0-\u08FF\uFB50-\uFDFF\uFE70-\uFEFF\U00010E60\U00010E7F\U00010EC0-\U00010EFF\U0001EC70-\U0001ECBF\U0001ED00-\U0001ED4F\U0001EE00-\U0001EEFF]+", text)

This differs a bit from your approach, though, in that it will pick up substrings that consist of Arabic characters, even if they are in a word with non-Arabic characters.
Alternately, remove all non-Arabic, non-whitespace characters from text — with a bit of postprocessing to remove extra whitespace:
cleaned_text = re.sub(r"[^\s\u0600-\u06FF\u0750-\u077F\u0870-\u089F\u08A0-\u08FF\uFB50-\uFDFF\uFE70-\uFEFF\U00010E60\U00010E7F\U00010EC0-\U00010EFF\U0001EC70-\U0001ECBF\U0001ED00-\U0001ED4F\U0001EE00-\U0001EEFF]+", "", text)
cleaned_text = re.sub(r"\s*\n\s*", "\n", cleaned_text).strip()
cleaned_text = re.sub(r"(\s)\s*", r"\1", cleaned_text)

If you install the package regex, which upgrades the Python's regular expression system, you can just write
import regex

arabic_word_list = regex.findall(r"\p{IsArabic}+", text)

and
cleaned_text = regex.sub(r"[^\s\p{IsArabic}]+", "", text)
cleaned_text = regex.sub(r"\s*\n\s*", "\n", cleaned_text).strip()
cleaned_text = regex.sub(r"(\s)\s*", r"\1", cleaned_text)

Your own approach can also be supercharged with this; first split into words by any non-word characters, then filter the list to just words containing only Arabic characters:
word_list = regex.split("\W+", text)
arabic_word_list = [
    word for word in words
    if regex.match(r"^\p{IsArabic}+$", word)
]

This only finds complete words that consist only of Arabic characters, like your code.
It is of course possible to backport this to only use built-in regular expression library, by replacing \p{IsArabic} with the monstrous character class above.
It is equivalent to the simpler and more performant
arabic_word_list = regex.findall(r"\b\p{IsArabic}+\b", text)

however, this is much harder to express with standard Python regular expressions, since \b will not function correctly.

The cor problem with \b is that re's definition of \b and \w differ from Unicode's. But then that isn't surprising since  quite a few of Pythons string methods differ form Unicode's definitions.

@Andj Yes. This is precisely why I am only using \b with regex package, and not with re. Of course, I can't read Arabic, and I do not know anything about Inherited.

its not specifically an Arabic Issue, for instance to capture Latin script text, you need to handle Latin, Inherited and Common scripts. Unicode has three special scripts: Common (Zyyy), Inherited (Zinh), and Unknown (Zzzz). Common includes multiscript characters like general punctuation, arabic digits, etc. Inherited includes things like combining diacritics or other characters shared by more than one script. So a string in a single language will likely have at least two scripts.

in hindsight I should have used r'\b\p{scx=Arabic}+\b' instead.

Our general approach is to:

Create a set of forbidden characters (English characters such as ABC)
Separate the string into different words
Find the set of letters used in each word.
For each and every word, check to see if the set of letters in that word contain a letters that are contained in the set of forbidden characters.

# convert all letters to upper-case 
text = text.upper()

# `enset` stands for `English set`  
enset = set(chr(32) + "©ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890")

word_boundaries = set("-*:;.|?\"\'“”" + chr(8205))

# replace all word boundary characters
# with the space character
# a space (` `) is character number 32

text = "".join(ch if (not ch in word_boundaries) else chr(32) for ch in text)

print(text)

words = text.split()

for word in words:

    # `wset` stands for `word set`
    wset = set(word)

    wset_and_enset = enset.intersection(wset)

    if len(wset_and_enset) < 1:
        print(word)

